# Why is my propel cascade blocked by foreign key constraints?

Tags: php, foreign-keys, constraints, propel, cascade

I have the following structure in the databse:

[image]

In my code I first create a Company, then a logbook, then a number of schedules, then a user, then a logbook responsibility. Sort of like this (not exact code for conciseness, but I don't *think* that matters:

```
<?php

$company = new Company();
$company->setSomething(123);

$logbook = new Logbook();
$logbook->setSomething('abc');
$logbook->setCompany($company);

$schedules = array();
for ($x=0; $x<$something; $x++) {
  $schedule = new Schedule();
  $schedule->setSomething(doSomethingWithSomething($something[$x]);
  $schedule->setLogbook($logbook);
  $schedules[] = $schedule;
}

$user = new User();
$user->setSomething('something');
$user->setCompany($company);
$user->setCurrentLogbook($logbook);

$logbookResponsibility = new LogbookResponsibility();
$logbookResponsibility->setLogbook($logbook);
$logbookResponsibility->setResponsibilityId(1);
$logbookResponsibility->setUser($user);

$errors = someFormOfCheck();

if (!$errors) {
  $user->save();
  $logbookResponsibility->save();
  foreach ($schedules as $schedule) {
    $schedule->save();
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`logbook`.`logbook_responsibility`, CONSTRAINT `fk_logbook_responsbility_user` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)' in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\pear\propel\connection\DebugPDOStatement.php:90
```

The `logbook_responsibility` table is made up of three foreign keys, each which have a `RESTRICT` on the updates, because I don't want it to be possible to delete a user, logbook or type of responsibility if a logbook responsibility exists. I believe the problem, however, is determined by the order of the cascade.

If I take out the `$logbookResponsibility` parts altogether, it works perfectly. If I put the `$logbookResponsibility` parts *after* the `$user->save();` and then issue a `$logbookResponsibility->save();` as well, that also works perfectly.

My question, then, is where abouts am I going wrong? What am I presuming incorreclty or doing wrong, to make the cascade work? Or is there something else that might be stopping it?

**Update:** If I do the following, it works just fine:

```
$company->save();
$logbook->save();
$user->save();
$logbookResponsibility->save();
foreach ($schedules as $scheudle) {
  $schedule->save();
}
```

i.e. if I save them manually first instead of relying on the cascade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't give you a good, direct answer to the exact problem you're seeing, but I've encountered similarly confusing issues with foreign keys and relationships in Propel. My best practice has now become setting IDs manually rather than allowing Propel to attempt to manage setting them through defined relationships. In this case, that would mean not calling `$logbookResponsibility->setLogbook()` or `$logbookResponsibility->setUser()` at all. Instead, call `$logbookResponsibility->setLogbookId()` and `$logbookResponsibility->setUserId()` after you have called `save()` on `$user` and `$logbook`.

Propel does a lot of things by reference, which can have unintended consequences when you're dealing with foreign keys and are setting relationships by calling methods expecting objects (e.g. `setLogbook()`) rather than methods expecting the relationship's ID (e.g. `setLogbookId()`).

Comment: Fair point, thanks, though notice my update. I can use the same syntax (passing objects about) if I just do a manual save instead of the cascade. I think now it's annoying me more that I don't know *why*.

Comment: I've felt that same pain. The why is going to come down to some deep pass-by-reference issue in Propel. Propel is either (a) trying to execute the INSERT on `$logbookResponsibility` without first doing the INSERT on `$user`, or (b) failing to pass `$user` by reference somewhere and issuing an UPDATE statement that doesn't include user.id. Have you tried having Propel dump its prepared statement so that you can look at it?

Comment: Setting IDs manually is a pain, but if you want to do one save to cascade down the relationship chain it's probably what you need to do. That said, my solution has been to do manual, individual save() calls as in your update.

Comment: Setting this as the answer as it provides plenty of information on the matter so any potential readers can make their own educated decision. thanks a lot!